# Park car near Paris

Tags: automobiles, paris

Coming to Paris from Brussels. Planning to stay in Paris one day. I know that it is not good option to go to center by car. What is the best place to leave car in order avoid expensive payment and traffic and have good approach to city center?

Comment: How long are you staying in Paris? Where are you staying?

Comment: I'm not planning to sty in Paris, but somewhere not far from it for one night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of "Parcs relais" close to metro, train or RER stations. You can find a map here:

http://www.navigo.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/stif_plan_parcs_relais.pdf

Note however that some may be quite busy.

A better alternative is probably to take the train directly from Brussels to Paris. It will be quicker, you'll get directly to the city center, and if you book in advance, it will probably be cheaper as well.

Comment: Round trip by train costs 80 eur per person and I have 3 passengers. It is not cheep option comparing to car.

Comment: @vico This is probably the best answer you’ll get given the sparse information you provided in your question. If you narrow it down to where you’ll be staying and possibly which central area(s) you’re most interested in, and how much you’re prepared to spend, for example, you may get something better.